# Multiple selects with different conditions?

Tags: sql, select

I have three columns in my database, mark1, mark2 and value. I wish to select the SUM of Value where
mark1=1 AND mark2=1,
mark1=1 AND mark2=2,
.
.
.
mark1=2 AND mark2=1,
mark1=2 AND mark2=2,

.
.
.

And all other possible combinations for mark1 and mark2, which would be 100 cases. Is there a smarter way to do this than writing 100 different selects?

Comment: select t.mark1,t.mark2,sum(t.value) from your_table t group by t.mark1,t.mark2

Comment: 1) MySQL != SQL Server - please correct your tags. 2) Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Sergey suggestion will give you the results you want for every combination found in the table. If there are combinations that may not be in the table that you want to account for (where their sum(value) would obviously be 0) then you'll need a new table that has columns `mark1` and `mark2` that holds just the combinations you are looking for and using that table to LEFT OUTER JOIN to your existing table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple grouping query.

```
SELECT Mark1, Mark2, SUM(value) AS SumOfValue
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Mark1, Mark2
```